# Reiniciar aplicación e C#

Tags: c#

estoy trabajando con sockets y en la aplicación cliente, cada que intento reiniciar mi aplicación

```
Application.ExitThread();
Application.Restart();
```

Me genera un error en esta linea, diciendo que la operación ha sido finalizada por el cliente, anteriormente funcionaba correctamente, lo único que hice fue generar el ejecutable de la aplicación y ahora no encuentro como solucionar :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, ami me pasa lo mismo, pero supongo es por que lo estas corriendo desde el IDE, pero si ejecutas la Aplicación real no te da ese problema y funciona correctamente.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, y sí, la ejecuté pero me dice que ocurrió un problema y que se detuvo la aplicación.

Comment: Puedes poner una captura de exactamente que te dice ?

Comment: Has probado a cerrar los sockets antes de reiniciar?

Comment: Hola, mil gracias por sus respuestas. 
Y sí, Pikoh el problema es que no se había cerrado el socket de la aplicación mientras intentaba ejecutarla de nuevo y por ende, el puerto seguía estando ocupado. 
Debía cerrarlos primero. :)